# ¿Por qué está expresión regular en PHP devuelve true siendo tan sencilla?

Tags: php, regex

En PHP tengo esto y se supone que si '$campo' tiene números me debe retornar 'false', pero retorna 'true' ¿a qué se debe?

```
if(!preg_match('/[a-záéíóúäëïöüñ\s]/', $campo))
{
    $sePuedeContinuar = false;
    echo "Este campo solo permite caracteres alfabéticos";
}
```

Me muestra el mensaje de error (como debería ser)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si le agrego una letra, funciona como si la expresión regular arrojara true
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Contra que estas probando esto?? porque contra numeros tira false...

Comment: ¿Estás mandando un string que contiene números además de letras?

Answer (score 5):

Las expresiones regulares **no tienen una posición de inicio o fin concreto**, salvo que tú digas lo contrario.

Cuando se prueba una expresión regular, se prueba en el primer caracter del string. Si desde ahí no hace match, entonces se avanza un caracter más y se vuelve a probar de nuevo toda la expresión regular. Mientras no haga match se irán avanzando los caracteres hasta que o se haga match o se acabe el string (y falle)

Así pues, cuando escribes `... preg_match('/[a-záéíóúäëïöüñ\s]/', $campo)`estás diciendo *busca un caracter del alfabeto*.

Si lo pruebas contra el string `123a4` esto es lo que sucede:

Primero se prueba `[a-záéíóúäëïöüñ\s]` contra `123a4` y falla, puesto que `1` no es un caracter de los admitidos. Así pues, avanzamos una posición.

Luego se prueba `[a-záéíóúäëïöüñ\s]` contra `23a4` y falla, puesto que `2` no es un caracter de los admitidos. Así pues, avanzamos una posición.

Luego se prueba `[a-záéíóúäëïöüñ\s]` contra `3a4` y falla, puesto que `3` no es un caracter de los admitidos. Así pues, avanzamos una posición.

Finalmente se prueba `[a-záéíóúäëïöüñ\s]` contra `a4` y hace *match*, puesto que `a` es un caracter admitido.

Como ha hecho match, ya no se sigue mirando, podemos terminar.

La situación cambia completamente con la expresión regular modificada: `^([a-záéíóúäëïöüñ\s])+$`. En este caso estás diciendo que desde el *inicio* `^` hasta el *final* `$` solo pueden existir una sucesión de caracteres que son letras del alfabeto. Por lo tanto, es imposible que esa expresión regular haga match en medio de un string ya que al intentar buscar `^` en mitad de un string, siempre fallaría.

Por otro lado, como además especificas el final de un string sabes que la expresión regular no puede terminar *antes de hora*.

Por ejemplo `^[a-z]+` no haría lo que esperas contra `abc123` porque la expresión regular podría terminar en `abc` y validaría, al no obligar que llegue hasta el final.

Así pues, para tu caso es obligatorio especificar el inicio y fin de string.

Finalmente, comentar que algunos otros lenguajes de programación tienen diferentes métodos para utilizar expresiones regulares **y algunos de ellos utilizan `^` y `$` de manera *implícita***.

Por ejemplo, en java el método `match` añade automáticamente `^` y `$` a la expresión regular. Por contra, el método `find` no lo hace.

Estas dos instrucciones serían equivalentes en Java:

```
Pattern.compile("^[a-z]+$").matcher(miString).find();

Pattern.compile("[a-z]+").matcher(miString).matches();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar usar la expresión `'/\\d/'` en el caso de que solo desees comprobar si la cadena contiene números. Recuerda que `preg_match()` retorna la cantidad de coincidencias. En el caso de que las coincidencias sean mayor a 0(Cero), quiere decir que contiene numeros. Un ejemplo:

**Código PHP**

```
<?php
$srt1 = "abc";
$srt2 = "a3c";
$srt3 = 'a3./c';
$srt4 = "a./c";

 preg_match('/\\d/', $srt1) > 0 ? false : true;  // devuelve True 
 preg_match('/\\d/', $srt2) > 0 ? false : true;  // devuelve False 
 preg_match('/\\d/', $srt3) > 0 ? false : true;  // devuelve False 
 preg_match('/\\d/', $srt4) > 0 ? false : true;  // devuelve True 

?>
```

Espero que te sirva y cualquier duda consultas. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer era por no poner los caracteres que indican el inicio y el final de la expresión, incluyéndolos, esta quedaría así:

```
if(!preg_match('/^([a-záéíóúäëïöüñ\s])+$/', $campo)) // '^' y '$'
{
    $sePuedeContinuar = false;
    echo "Este campo solo permite caracteres alfabéticos";
}
```